# virtual host from IP address

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

if I don't have an domain and what I have is IP address.. how can I create a virtual host? can someone give me an example of a nginx.conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hosts file. Add server directive to nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name   example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;
}
```

Create /var/www/example.com:

```
# mkdir /var/www/example.com
# echo "example.com virtualhost" >> /var/www/example.com/index.html
```

Add example.com to your local system hosts files(%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\ in Windows):

```
#echo "IP example.com" > /etc/hosts
```

Also you can use DynDNS.

Comment: so then to access example.com I can do IP/example

Comment: No. You need use DNS name. Web bowser add Host header when you use DNS name. Nginx use Host header to route virtual hosts.

Comment: can you show what you mean by that?

Comment: Create example.com and www.example.com virtual hosts with different content. Then open "example.com" and "www.example.com", you see different web site.

Comment: well...I want to be able to access it from outside the server

Comment: when you say open "example.com" and www.example.com, you're referring to from the machine/server itself right? what if I want everyone else in this world to be able to see that site?

Comment: Create real DNS record

Comment: in other words I need a domain right?

Comment: Yes, you need domain

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use a non name based virtual host at which point you can only have one site per IP address, in this case you can just type the IP into your webbrowser. The default nginx config on most systems should already have this setup for you

If you want to put more than site on an IP you have to use name based virtualhosts, you set these up as normal if you did have a domain name, but to be able to see them you would have to edit your hosts file to add the domain records you set your virtualhosts on. You would have to do this on every computer you want to access those sites from and it does require admin privileges to each machine

NOTE: you dont actually need to own the domains you use, but i would recommend it or at least not using common domains